# Bukkit EntityExplode physics and regeneration of blocks

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I am having this issue with my code where when a tnt or creeper explodes, blocks will fly everywhere but when the blocks have landed everything should regenerate but it dosen't. Anyone who has a conclusion?

Here is my code:

```
      @EventHandler
      void onExplode1(EntityExplodeEvent event) {

    for(Block block : event.blockList()) {

        if(block.getType() != Material.TNT) {
            float x = -0.4F + (float) (Math.random() * 0.9D);
            float y = -1.2F + (float) (Math.random() * 1.9D);
            float z = -0.9F + (float) (Math.random() * 1.4D);

            FallingBlock falling = block.getWorld().spawnFallingBlock(block.getLocation(), block.getType(), block.getData());
            falling.setVelocity(new Vector(x, y, z));
            falling.setDropItem(true);

            block.setType(Material.AIR);

        }

        if(block.getType() != Material.AIR) {

            final BlockState state = block.getState();

            int delay;

            if(block.getType().hasGravity()) {

                delay = 80;

            } else {

                delay = 80 + (int)(Math.random()*60);

            }

            // Set block to air so that no blocks drop
            block.setType(Material.AIR);

            // Regenerate all the blocks in a random order
            Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    state.update(true, false);

                }

            }, delay);

        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to let the block appear after it landed? At the location the block was before the explosion, or there where the block lands?

Comment: Yes, I want the blocks to come back at their exact position.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to store the Entitys you created and then get back the Locations... Here is an example code... It doesn't have to work as well as others but it's a try.

```
package me.mcplayhd.testt;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.entity.FallingBlock;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityChangeBlockEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDamageEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityDeathEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityExplodeEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.util.Vector;

public class ExplodeBlocks extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    public void onEnable() {
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    }

    HashMap<FallingBlock, Location> blocks = new HashMap<FallingBlock, Location>();

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @EventHandler
    void onEntityExplode(EntityExplodeEvent e) {
        Iterator<Block> bi = e.blockList().iterator();
        while(bi.hasNext()) {
            Block b = bi.next();
            if(b.getType() != Material.TNT) {
                bi.remove();

                Material m = b.getType();
                byte d = b.getData();

                b.setType(Material.AIR);

                float x = -0.4F + (float) (Math.random() * 0.9D);
                float y = -1.2F + (float) (Math.random() * 1.9D);
                float z = -0.9F + (float) (Math.random() * 1.4D);

                FallingBlock falling = b.getWorld().spawnFallingBlock(b.getLocation(), m, d);
                falling.setVelocity(new Vector(x, y, z));
                falling.setDropItem(false);

                blocks.put(falling, b.getLocation());
            }
        }
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onEntityDamage(EntityDamageEvent e) {
        if(e.getEntity() instanceof FallingBlock) {
            FallingBlock fb = (FallingBlock) e.getEntity();
            if(blocks.containsKey(fb)) {
                e.setCancelled(true);
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @EventHandler
    public void onEneityDeath(EntityDeathEvent e) {
        if(e.getEntity() instanceof FallingBlock) {
            FallingBlock fb = (FallingBlock) e.getEntity();
            if(blocks.containsKey(fb)) {
                Location loc = blocks.get(fb);
                loc.getBlock().setType(fb.getMaterial());
                loc.getBlock().setData(fb.getBlockData());
                blocks.remove(fb);
                fb.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @EventHandler
    public void onEntityChangeBlock(EntityChangeBlockEvent e) {
        if(e.getEntity() instanceof FallingBlock) {
            FallingBlock fb = (FallingBlock) e.getEntity();
            if(blocks.containsKey(fb)) {
                e.setCancelled(true);
                Location loc = blocks.get(fb);
                loc.getBlock().setType(fb.getMaterial());
                loc.getBlock().setData(fb.getBlockData());
                blocks.remove(fb);
                fb.remove();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is it doesn't work 100% but most of the blocks will be restored. The others I don't know, but I think you will find the cause...

Sry if this doesn't help at all